# Why do i get wrong filesystem error on mounting external drive whilst correct ntfs-utils is installed?

Tags: mount, filesystem, ntfs, sd-card, usb-drive

since today I get the following message when inserting usbstick/sd card:

> **Aankoppelen bestandssysteem is mislukt** 
>  
>   Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/wouter/Kali Live: Command-line
>   `mount -t "iso9660" -o
>   "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1001,gid=1001,iocharset=utf8,mode=0400,dmode=0500"
>   "/dev/sdb1" "/media/wouter/Kali Live"' exited with non-zero exit
>   status 32: mount: block device /dev/sdb1 is write-protected, mounting
>   read-only mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on
>   /dev/sdb1,
>          missing codepage or helper program, or other error
>          In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
>          dmesg | tail  or so
>
> (udisks-error-quark, 0)

Here is the output of `dmesg | tail`

> [  995.732144] sd 12:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
>  
>   [  996.478994] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdb] 7643136 512-byte logical blocks: (3.91 GB/3.64 GiB)
>  
>   [  996.479683] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
>  
>   [  996.479692] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
>  
>   [  996.480485] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
>  
>   [  996.480493] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
>  
>   [  996.522644]  sdb: sdb1
>  
>   [  996.525979] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
>  
>   [  997.561414] ISOFS: Unable to identify CD-ROM format.
>  
>   [  999.938443] ISOFS: Unable to identify CD-ROM format.

It was working perfect until now. I do have `ntfs-3g` installed, so this could not be the problem.

Comment: Please be more specific - what kind of media to you try to mount? How is it connected? What do expect on the media?

Comment: The last time this external drive was connected to a Microsoft Windows system, did it work? Did you disconnect it politely, or just yank the cable? You should probably mount it on Windows the dismount it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, it was a matter of corrupt stick. I had a few memory sticks/sd cards after each other which gave me the same error which made me think that it was a settings fault, but it turned out to be the sticks themselves. Problem solved